# Getting tags from AWS ECS clusters return empty lists

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I need to read the tags from my ECS clusters. I successfully list all of my clusters with a *describeClusters()* call. Then I make a *getTags()* call, and it incorrectly returns an empty list.

```java
    List<Cluster> clusters = clusterDescriptionResult.getClusters();
    for (Cluster cluster : clusters) {
        String clusterArn = cluster.getClusterArn();
        //System.out.println("Cluster: " + clusterArn);
        List<Tag> tagList = cluster.getTags();
```

I figured I must be doing something not right, so as a test, I rewrote the code in Python.

```py
    clusterList = ecsClient.list_clusters()
    for clusterArn in clusterList["clusterArns"]:
        tagListData = ecsClient.list_tags_for_resource(resourceArn=clusterArn)
        tagList = tagListData["tags"]
```

(Edit: this Python code works just fine -- see comments for why it was not working initially)
Rather than giving me an empty list, *list_tags_for_resource()* prefers to throw an exception:
AttributeError: 'ECS' object has no attribute 'list_tags_for_resource'

At this point, I have to wonder... do I have outdated packages? According to my pom.xml, I'm using version 1.11.604 (Java), or boto3-1.9.202 botocore-1.12.202 (Python), which appear current so far as I can tell (Aug 2019).

Edit: I have now tried from the command line, and that does work:

```sh
    aws ecs list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn {cluster_arn}
```

Comment: In a good-news/bad-news sort of way, I have figured out the issue with the Python code (I forgot I was using Anaconda, so I updated the general system boto3, not the specific Conda environment boto3), so yay for that, but it really is the Java code that I need to fix, so, yeah, sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in the API. The workaround is to use the ListTagsForResourceRequest() call for now, which does correctly return the tags for the cluster.

```java
    ListTagsForResourceRequest tagRequest = new ListTagsForResourceRequest().withResourceArn(clusterArn);
    ListTagsForResourceResult tagResult = amazonECS.listTagsForResource(tagRequest);
    List<Tag> tagList = tagResult.getTags();
```